# Why it takes only the last 4 bits in my following example?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char c=48;
   int i, mask=01;

   for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
   {
       printf("%c", c|mask);
       mask = mask<<1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I am learning for an exam, and this was a solved exercise with the answer: 12480 because %c takes only the last 4 bits. I don't understand why, as I know that sizeof char is 1 byte.

Comment: Make mask also a character.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. That printf is called 5 times, and 5 characters are printed out.

Comment: %c doesn't take only the last 4 bits. The problem is that when the mask becomes  16 (0x10) you or 1 with 1 (the character 48 is 0x30, with that bit already set)

Comment: I have no idea why you are talking about 4 bits or what the problem is here. If you or 0x30 with 0x10 you get 0x30 which is `0` as is printed as the last character. There's nothing about four bits here. Could you clarify by asking a question?

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  Given `char c` and `int mask`, `c|mask` results in an `int`.  Calling `printf()` on an `int` with a `%c` format specifier results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle No, the `%c` printf format specifier expects an `int`. There is no undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle-- The `%c` conversion specifier expects an `int`: ["If no l length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the binary representation of 48:

```
2^ 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
   ---------------
   0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

The last 4 bits are not set.  On the first 4 iterations of the loop, the mask sets one of those bits in the result, and the result reflects the change.  On the last iteration, the mask is setting a bit which is already set, so there is no change for the last character printed.

As for what is being printed, in ASCII 48 is the character code for `0`.  The following digits are in order after that one.  When you mask in the values for the first 4 iterations, because none of the bits in the value 48 are set in the mask, it is effectively the same as adding.  So the first 4 characters printed have ASCII values 49 (`1`), 50 (`2`), 52 (`4`), and 56 (`8`).

Answer (score 1):

Character code 48 is usually `0`. When it's or'd with one, it prints digit 1.  Then it prints the digits 2, 4, 8. Finally, 48|16 = 48, so it prints 0.

Answer (score 0):

It takes them all, however the last time around you or that 1 with a bit that already is 1 (48 is 110000 in binary)

Comment: Ok, pur și simplu prima dată faci 48|1, care e 49. Apoi 48|2==50, apoi 48|4==52, apoi 48|3==56. Nimic special. Însă 48|16==48, pentru că al 5-lea bit de la dreapta e deja 1 și făcând sau cu un alt 1 nu face nimic. (btw, we should keep it in English on this website/